Allow any origin (temporarily) to connect from Hostinger frontend to AWS Beanstalk
My situation is the following, I have:

A frontend and a database hosted in Hostinger
A backend (C# web api core .Net 7) in AWS Beanstalk
I must connect all of them for a couple of weeks
Backend works fine with database
Running my frontend locally (with AWS API link) works fine
Running requests from Postman (with AWS API link) works fine
But, when I upload my website to Hostinger and try to connect to backend I only receive a CONNECTION REFUSED error

I tried creating an EC2 security group with inbound rules that allows any origin and also Hostinger IP but seems to be not working. (I know that is not secure allow any origin but I need this for private testing/learning and temporarily while other team works on the original laravel backend)
What can I do to allow any origin as inbound to my Beanstalk project?
Ps: In the project, Program.cs is enabled (temporarily) to allow any origin in its CORS

Is there a load balancer in front of your EB environment? Do you have access logs turned on on the load balancer?
